# comparen today's date with date format YYYY-DD-MM in dynamodb table

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table of name: **DATETABLE** with date values YYYY-DD-MM and data type is String in **AWS dynamodb**
it has partition key has date which is String

```
const currentdate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
client.query({
  TableName: 'date',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'date = :todaydate',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':todaydate': currentdate
  }
})
```

I only to want to compare date values with current(today's) date like using key condition which will be

```
 KeyConditionExpression: 'date = :currentdate',
```

return true or false based on input. which will be like direct query
SELECT * FROM date WHERE DATE = 2022-14-12(current date) (table value)

**Error:** UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '7' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':date']

Comment: Hopefully your date values aren't actually YYYY-DD-MM.

Comment: they are actually in that format in table

Comment: Ouch, hard to understand how these things happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const currentdate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
client.query({
  TableName: 'date',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'date = :todaydate',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':todaydate': {'S':currentdate}
  }
})
```